# Set free the data chunk blocked by read() from input stream?

Tags: java, sockets, java-io

I use `getInputStream().read()` to check if client has disconnected from the server. It works but the `read()` function, as it states in documentation, blocks the first letter of message. So instead of printing "Hello", it prints "ello". How can I make the `read()` function 'let go' of the first letter?
Here is the following server code to wait for input:

```
            while(true)
            {
                if(socket.getInputStream().read()==-1)//if no response
                    break;
                String msg = bufferedReader.readLine();
                if(msg!=null) {
                    System.out.println("Received message: " + msg);
                }

            }
```

If there is no way to go around that, what's the alternative to `getInputStream().read()` to detect client disconnection?

Comment: The first character was returned from read(). Save it.  The complete message is what you get from read() plus what you get from readLine().  Having said that, the first read() seems pointless to me.  readLine() will throw an IOException, which you can catch.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'the data chunk blocked by `read()`. If there is any data at all, `read()` will return it; and if the peer has disconnected, it will return -1 instead. Unclear what you're asking. NB It does not state in the documentation that it 'blocks the first letter of the message'. You have misunderstood. It blocks until at least one character has been read, or EOS or an error occurs.

Comment: @passer-by If the peer has disconnected, `readLine()` will return null, but you are otherwise correct in that the first `read()` is completely unnecessary here.

Comment: @passer-by 
@user207421}
Thank you, I removed read(), added try/catch and everything works now. You can post an answer so I can mark it as solved.

Comment: answer written up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right approach is to not use the separate read() at all.  Simply handle readLine() telling you the underlying connection is gone.

For a robust solution, there are two cases you should handle:

1. readLine() returns null; this is 'normal end of stream' and I'd expect it to happen if the client closed the connection cleanly.
2. readLine() throws an IOException, which you need try-catch to deal with. This can happen if the connection is terminated abruptly, possibly if the client exits without closing the connection.

It's for you to decide whether those two possibilities are treated identically, based in your program requirements.